# JavaScript Validation form did not stop on error

Tags: javascript, html

I am making simple html form and doing validation using javascript.. But my form did not stop on error...

```
if(document.register.fname.value=="")
{

alert("plz enter username");
document.register.fname.focus();
alert("plz enter username");
return false;
}
```

Html Part is....

```
<input type="image" src="img/signup.PNG" alt="Sign Up" value="signup" onsubmit="return regis()" />
```

Even if I left the blank it goes on another page.... plz help me that what is the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the validation javascript on your form as appear below:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

If you want to validate when the submit button is pressed try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit this form" onclick="validateForm('myForm');return false;" />
```

Comment: It works on alert but When using the following code it again go to the next page.                  if(document.register.fname.value=="")
{
 
 document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML="plz enter username";
 return false;
 
 
}  @Thanos

Answer (score 1):

`onsubmit` only works on a `form` element, not an `input` element. Place your `onsubmit` inline handler in the `form` element.

A better option would be to use `addEventListener` as in:

```
document.register.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if(document.register.fname.value === "")
  {
    alert("plz enter username");
    document.register.fname.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the attribute `onsubmit="return regis()"` into the `form` tag of your form.

Like this

```
<form onsubmit="return regis()" ...
```